# masterslider jquery, video not running on mobile

Tags: masterslider

I have video issue with masterslider at alamo1.com. go there using desktop and you will see a background video with text overlay. On mobile the video is no longer playing. This was working. I need a fresh of eyes on it to see what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this line of code in masterslider.js that prevent video to be shown on mobile:

```
if (window._mobile) return void $video.remove();
```

Either you can remove this line of code or I just update this code according to my need like:

```
if (window._mobile && $video.data("hide-on-mobile")) return void $video.remove();
```

Use this attribute in my html like this:

```
<video data-autopause="false" data-mute="true" data-hide-on-mobile="false" data-loop="true" data-fill-mode="fill">
   <source src="upload/stockholm-city.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```